# supervisord can't find command in virtualenv folder

Tags: python, virtualenv, supervisord

My `supervisord.conf` contains a bunch of programs like so:

```
[program:gtaskqueue_puller_1]
directory=/root/scripts/gtaskqueue_puller
command=venv/bin/gtaskqueue_puller "foo"
autostart=true
autorestart=true

[program:gtaskqueue_puller_2]
directory=/root/scripts/gtaskqueue_puller
command=venv/bin/gtaskqueue_puller "bar"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

But sometimes when I restart supervisord, I get

```
can't find command venv/bin/gtaskqueue_puller
```

But when I `cd` into the directory and run the same command, it works as expected.

Comment: can you provide absolute path to the venv/bin? supervisor conf provides `directory` directive http://supervisord.org/configuration.html

Comment: Yes, I already set the `directory` option. Just tried using the full path in the command, and it's working. Weird.

Comment: I can see the same behaviour - sometimes supervisor can't find command with relative path even if directory is set and you can run command from this directory manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes supervisor can't find command with relative path even if directory is setup.

So use:

```
[program:gtaskqueue_puller_1]
directory=/root/scripts/gtaskqueue_puller
command=/root/scripts/gtaskqueue_puller/venv/bin/gtaskqueue_puller "foo"
autostart=true
autorestart=true

[program:gtaskqueue_puller_2]
directory=/root/scripts/gtaskqueue_puller
command=/root/scripts/gtaskqueue_puller/venv/bin/gtaskqueue_puller "bar"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

rather than:

```
[program:gtaskqueue_puller_1]
directory=/root/scripts/gtaskqueue_puller
command=venv/bin/gtaskqueue_puller "foo"
autostart=true
autorestart=true

[program:gtaskqueue_puller_2]
directory=/root/scripts/gtaskqueue_puller
command=venv/bin/gtaskqueue_puller "bar"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```